# Formula with datetime in Crystal Reports 2011 VS 2010, does not filter properly

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports-2010

I have a formula in my report that I use to filter data and time periods, this formula I am using a static parameter of type DateTime, with the option enabled Allow range values​​, only that the rest of this standard.

I created a new formula in the Formula Fields to the following expression:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
DateTimeVar date1;
DateTimeVar date2;
date1:=Minimum ({?DateRange});
date2:=Maximum ({?DateRange});
"Periodo de filtro: " + ToText(date1) + " até " + ToText(date2)
```

I'm using CrystalReportViewer in asp.net how to view my report when I run my report stating the date and start time and ending date and time the report that I returned all the data in my table.

My database is receiving a field datetime2(0) in YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS, the CrystalReportViewer component inform the date and time in the format DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS may have some relationship between the formats for dates with the filter does not work?

Comment: Please post your record-selection formula.

Answer (score 0):

Your record-selection formula should be:

```
{table.date} IN {?date range}
```

If you want to *display* the date-range parameter:

```
//{@date-range display}; it may need to be adjusted to handle the 'no lower bound' and 'no upper bound' settings
ToText( Minimum({?date range}), "dd/mm/yyyy" ) + " - " + ToText( Maximum({?date range}), "dd/mm/yyyy" )
```

Comment: It did not work, tried to switch to "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "yyyy/mm/dd", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss", has no errors, but keeps returning all data the table, I'll do a test to uninstall my Sql Server Express 2008 r2 Brazilian Portuguese and reinstall with ENU to test I believe can be a problem with my Standard Date Format sqlsever. sqlsever. Something strange is happening to me when I try to insert this function {TB_GeracaoM1.Timestamp} IN {?DateRange}. Crystal reports shows me a message (The date-time is required here.)  Showing my table field in Formulas Workshop!